# CSS(?) Preventing a table from printing past the first page with Ctrl + P

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm a novice developer coming in mid-way to a Vue-generated project with many components. We're also using the quasar framework for some of our tables.

We have tables that should print out to at least 16 pages were they on landscape-legal, or saved to a PDF. However, when using `ctrl + P` to generate a print preview in Chrome, nothing past the screen view at the time `Ctrl + P` was pressed will show.

I've made some `@media` print queries to see if `overflow`, `z-index`, `display`, and any other CSS property I can think of might affect this but haven't had any success in prompting Chrome to generate more than one page in print preview. I have some confusion too about CSS precedence rules in the context of a Vue app, and how Quasar may also affect this.

UPDATE: SOLVED (the below is in stylus css)

```
@media print
  header
    display none !important

  *
    overflow unset !important
    height unset !important
    min-height unset !important
    max-height unset !important

  .q-page-container
    padding-top 0 !important
    padding-left 0 !important

    .overflow-hidden
      overflow unset !important
  .q-table__card
    box-shadow unset !important
```

Comment: How are you displaying the tables, is it in a dynamic view that's paginated?

Comment: No pagination, on the front or back-end

Comment: On the front end, are you showing every table on one page or screen?

Comment: No, there are 3 different tables that get generated on 3 different views/pages once all values of a drop-down-cascading menu are selected. The screen display is fine, but printing displays cut off, it's almost as if ctrl + P were just a screenshot.

Comment: Are you doing anything to override the normal print functionality of the browser? Printing is only going to print what's on your current screen.

Comment: Unless there's boilerplate baked into Vue or Quasar that overrides or interferes with Chrome's default print-preview features, I don't think so. Printing should print everything generated on the page, everything that can be scrolled to as I understand it, and does for any other page/app, however in this project, Ctrl + P won't display anything below the screen-view at the time it's entered.

Comment: Can you share the view(s) that generate it? Won't know until you show it, but it sounds like you're not rendering it on the page until "something" happens which is why it isn't showing up on the print preview. Unless you are doing something to block the content from printing, but that sounds unlikely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- print preview would not be activated until after the page (and the entirely of its table) is rendered. All rows can be scrolled to on the screen, and on print-preview, the scroll bar is visible (you can scroll to the middle of the table, hit ctrl + P and see the middle of the table, but rows above and below that view are cut off, and the available pages to print is always just 1.)

Comment: Then that's a browser issue. Make sure your settings are enabled for multiple pages and not set to a single page or other constraints.

Comment: No other pages or projects seem to be affected

Comment: Ok, so could you share the code then?

Comment: Here's how one of our tables is brought it in the template section of one of the vue files using Quasar:

`q-table(:columns="dataset.columns", :visible="dataset.visible", :data="data.rows", row-key="name")`

Comment: 'Gets' for retrieving and refreshing the table go through our Vuex store which is tied indirectly to our SQL server. Not sure how relevant this is for you for this issue, apologies if that's extraneous.

Comment: SOLVED (my co-worker is amazing!!)
I had never seen the "unset" property before. This is written in stylus for Vue, use curly braces, commas, and semicolons where necessary

`@media print
  header
    display none !important

  *
    overflow unset !important
    height unset !important
    min-height unset !important
    max-height unset !important

  .q-page-container
    padding-top 0 !important
    padding-left 0 !important

    .overflow-hidden
      overflow unset !important

  .q-table__card
    box-shadow unset !important`

Comment: Can you please explain how that worked?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it reset all of the values across the entire project to offer a clean slate to style from at print time

Comment: Ok, so it was the site's styling that ruined printing for you then? That would make sense. Glad to hear it's working now!